# Set NfcV MaxTransceiveLength

Tags: android, xamarin.android, nfc, iso-15693

I have to use NFC-V for communication with the Wireless M-Bus protocol that transmits 256 byte packets. Can anyone tell me how can I change the MaxTransceiveLength property which is set to 253 bytes by default?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum transceive length is typically constrained by the underlying NFC hardware. Since that limit reflects that maximum length supported by the underlying hardware it can't usually<sup>1</sup> be changed through software.

<sup>1</sup>) It has been found that the limit indicated by the Android NFC stack (through the Xamarin API property `MaxTransceiveLength` or the Android API method `getMaxTransceiveLength()`) does not always reflect the actual limit imposed by the NFC hardware. However, changing that value would require modifications to the NFC stack.